# Comparing two Collections in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have two Collections in a Java class.The first collection contains previous data, the second contains updated data from the previous collection.

I would like to compare the two collections but I'm not sure of the best way to implement this efficiently.Both collections will contain the same amount of items.

Based then on the carType being the same in each collection I want to execute the carType method.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445/how-best-to-compare-two-collections-in-java-and-act-on-them

Comment: What result do you expect from the comparison; you want to extract the elements that didn't change ? do you need to know their index in the collections (it's the same in both)...

Comment: Apologies for the vague description pgras. The collections will be in the same order and the same size.Some of the data in the new collection will be updated from the previous collection.Based on carType,registrationNo and insurancePolicy being the same in both collections I will then execute some other code.

Comment: Future readers.  If you want to compare two collections.... based on the value(s) of SOME (or all) of the scalar properties of the ITEMs in the collection : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717638/how-to-compare-two-collections-for-equivalence-based-on-fields-from-different/40718320#40718320

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Difficult to help, because you didn't tell us *how* you like to compare the (equal-size) collections. Some ideas, hoping one will fit:

**Compare both collections if they contain the same objects in the same order**

```
Iterator targetIt = target.iterator();
for (Object obj:source)
  if (!obj.equals(targetIt.next()))
    // compare result -> false
```

**Compare both collections if they contain the same objects in the any order**

```
for (Object obj:source)
  if (target.contains(obj))
    // compare result -> false
```

**Find elements in other collection that has changed**

```
Iterator targetIt = target.iterator();
for (Object obj:source)
  if (!obj.equals(targetIt.next())
    // Element has changed
```

---

Based on your comment, this algorithm would do it. It collects all Cars that have been updated. If the method result is an empty list, both collections contain equal entries in the same order. The algorithm **relies** on a correct implementation of `equals()` on the `Car` type!

```
public List<Car> findUpdatedCars(Collection<Car> oldCars, Collection<Car> newCars)
  List<Car> updatedCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
  Iterator oldIt = oldCars.iterator();
  for (Car newCar:newCars) {
    if (!newCar.equals(oldIt.next()) {
      updatedCars.add(newCar);
    }
  }
  return updatedCars;
}
```

Comment: You are using `new` in your parameter which is not allowed. Also, where is this `new` used in `findUpdatedCars`?

Comment: @Shervin and @Andreas_D, thanks for the help guys. Very well explained. Very much appreciated!

Comment: @damien535: Remember that for this to work, you must override `hashCode()` and `equals()` in your `Car` object

Answer (score 21):

From the set arithmetics, the sets A and B are equal iff A subsetequal B and B subsetequal A. So, in Java, given two collections A and B you can check their equality without respect to the order of the elements with

```
boolean collectionsAreEqual = A.containsAll(B) && B.containsAll(A);
```

Comment: this statement is true for sets but may not be true for lists or other structures that permit duplicate entries (in other words, use sets when possible to simplify your logic)

Answer (score 6):

- Iterate over the first collection and add it into a `Map<Entity, Integer>` whereby `Entity` is the class being stored in your collection and the `Integer` represents the number of times it occurs.
- Iterate over the second collection and, for each element attempt to look it up in the `Map` - If it exists then decrement the `Integer` value by one and perform any action necessary when a match is found.  If the `Integer` value has reached zero then remove the (Entity, Integer) entry from the map.

This algorithm will run in linear time assuming you've implemented an efficient `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly updated one considering null values:

```
static <T> boolean equals(Collection<T> lhs, Collection<T> rhs) {
    boolean equals = false;
    if(lhs!=null && rhs!=null) {
       equals = lhs.size( ) == rhs.size( ) && lhs.containsAll(rhs)  && rhs.containsAll(lhs);
    } else if (lhs==null && rhs==null) {
       equals = true;
    }
 return equals;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If not worried about cases like (2,2,3), (2,3,3):

```
static <T> boolean equals(Collection<T> lhs, Collection<T> rhs) {
    return lhs.size( ) == rhs.size( ) && lhs.containsAll(rhs)  && rhs.containsAll(lhs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isEqualCollection(java.util.Collection a,
                                        java.util.Collection b)
```

Returns true if the given Collections contain exactly the same elements with exactly the same cardinalities.

That is, iff the cardinality of e in a is equal to the cardinality of e in b, for each element e in a or b.

**Parameters**:

- the first collection, must not be null
- the second
  collection, must not be null

**Returns**:
true if the collections contain the same elements with the same cardinalities.