# HashMap values().equals() is always return false even if comparing with another HashMap which has same value

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to check whether values of two hashmaps are equal to each other or not with using hashMap.values().equals(). But even if two HashMap have same values it's not considered as equal.

```
String s = "egg";
String t = "add";
int count = 0;
HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    String val = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));

    if (!hashMap.containsKey(val)) {
        count++;
        hashMap.put(val, count);
    } else {
        hashMap.put(val, hashMap.get(val));
    }
}

HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap2 = new HashMap<>();
int count2 = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < t.length(); j++) {
    String val = String.valueOf(t.charAt(j));

    if (!hashMap2.containsKey(val)) {
        count2++;
        hashMap2.put(val, count2);
    } else{
        hashMap2.put(val, hashMap2.get(val));
    }
}

if (hashMap.values().equals(hashMap2.values())) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: for example i have [1, 2] in both hashmaps. I check before if statement. It's same but if statement always return false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two Collections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085353/comparing-two-collections-in-java)

Comment: `hashMap.values()` is not equal to `hashMap2.values()` because the first is [2,1,3] and the second is [1,2,3]. The order in the values collection is determined by the order of keys and in the case of `HashMap` it's virtually unpredictable.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I was added wrong values. s = "egg"  and t = "add"  have same values but it's not correct to check via .values().equals() because collections cannot be equal as Ali Ben Zarrouk pointed as answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `hashMap.values()` is return `Collection<T>` we cannot compare it with `equals()`. Thanks to Ali Ben Zarrouk for help. Here is the implementation of how to check if values of two hashmaps are equal or not without using any third party library.

```
   if(areHashMapValuesEqual(hashMap.values(),hashMap2.values())){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

  static <T> boolean areHashMapValuesEqual(Collection<T> lhs, Collection<T> rhs) {
    boolean equals = false;
    if(lhs!=null && rhs!=null) {
        equals = lhs.size( ) == rhs.size( ) && lhs.containsAll(rhs)  && rhs.containsAll(lhs);
    } else if (lhs==null && rhs==null) {
        equals = true;
    }
    return equals;
}
```

Comment: This is good but I would name the method something like `equalsIgnoreOrder`. Otherwise it could be confusing as the same name `equals` in the `List` interface is dependent on order.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing two collections, they will never be equal because you're doing a reference compare on two different collections. Apache commons-collections has CollectionUtils#isEqualCollection, use that. Of course if you're creating you own class as value of the map, implement equals and hashCode in it.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The OP's code uses `equals()`, not `==`. There is no reference comparison in the code.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException The `Collection` returned by `HashMap.values()` does not override `equals`, so it uses the default implementation, which compares the references.