# compare java lists

Tags: java, list

in the loop , I make some actions then get and add string to the list1
after loop: list1 contains 2 strings : OK
now, in another loop I get value on each iteration which return me a string and I would like to check that strings in list1 aren't available in the second:

```
for(inti=0;i<nb;i++){
   value= table.getValue(i);
   list1.add(value);
}

for(int j=0;j<nb;j++){
   String toto = table.getValue(i);
   //do other actions

   //here verify that list1 doesn't contain toto
   //I tried :
   assetFalse(table.getValue(i).contains(list1)); //not OK !
}
```

Comment: read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445/how-best-to-compare-two-collections-in-java-and-act-on-them

Comment: what question are you asking??? What doesn't work?

Comment: I would like to make a list in the second loop then verify that content of list1 isn't available in list2

Comment: In your both for loops nothing is difference.In both cases you are using same data iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//here verify that list1 doesn't contain toto
//I tried :
assetFalse(table.getValue(i).contains(list1)); //not OK !
```

First the method is called asse**r**tFalse.

Second you're checking if `toto` contains the list ( `table.getValue(i)` is `toto`).
Note that your code could also be read as `assertFalse(toto.contains(list1));` (with the spelling fixed and using the assignment above).

Instead I guess you'd like to do this instead:

```
 assertFalse(list1.contains(toto));
```

Also note that in your two loops you iterate over the same collection (`table`) and the same indices ( 0 to `nb-1`). Thus `list` will always contain the values you check for (unless you're removing them somewhere) and thus your assertation will always fail.

Finally, please post compilable code: `inti=0;` won't compile as well as `assetFalse(...)` nor `String toto = table.getValue(i);`, since `i` isn't known in that loop (it is out of scope).

If you want us to help you, please put more effort into your questions.

**Edit**

If you want to compare two collections, you could also use a utility library like Apache Commons Collections, which has methods like `CollectionUtils.containsAny(collection1, collection2)` (this would return true if at least one element is present in both collections) etc.

Google Guava should have similar utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should be

```
assertFalse(list1.contains(table.getValue(i)));
```

If `getValue` returns a `String`, you cannot do a `contains` operation on it passing a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to check if a list (list1) is contained in a string. That does not make sense. Try it vice versa.

Comment: I would like to make a list in the second loop then verify that content of list1 isn't available in list2

Answer (score 0):

If you're just comparing lists of strings a simple contains() method should work.

```
for(String value: list2){

   //here verify that list1 doesn't contain string in list2
   if(list1.contains(value)){
      //Do something here.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing "i" in the second loop but it is declared in the first loop.